# What is the difference beteeen a solenoid's make current and inrush current?

Tags: relay, solenoid

Sorry if I'm just being noobish, but as I understand it, the make current is the maximum current that the solenoid can handle when switched on, but the inrush current is the maximum current it can handle when...switched on? What am I missing?

Comment: There is no inrush current. The solenoid is an inductor, the current will rise from zero based on R an L values. Solenoids have pull in current and hold current. The highest current is the current defined by the winding resistance alone.

Comment: As @JackCreasey rightly says, the inductor will do the opposite of allow inrush current - it will oppose the current flow then allow it to increase exponentially as it charges. It's the opposite effect to capacitance, which does draw an inrush current from an applied supply.

Comment: Solenoid **make** current?

Answer (score 9):

A solenoid designed for **AC supplies** will have an inrush current that can be significantly greater than the steady state current it takes when it has activated. It all depends on how the solenoid is initially supplied voltage and the part of the AC cycle that the voltage is applied. If you apply AC voltage to the solenoid at the peak of the waveform then there is little or no inrush current whereas if the solenoid is connected to an AC source as it passes through zero volts then the current waveform in the solenoid can reach an excessive value that causes magnetic saturation of the solenoid core and make the problem of inrush even worse.

Here's a table of numbers taken from the internet that can give some insight into the level of the problem: -

[image]

And here's what AC inrush current can look like when the applied AC voltage occurs at a zero crossing and at full peak: -

[image]

The top half of the picture above shows the problematic inrush current taking time to settle down. Solenoids, transformers, inductors and AC motors can all produce this effect because when lightly loaded, they are basically an inductor and the inductor current is proportional to the integral of applied voltage.

Comment: +1 I have spent too long in the low voltage DC world. Essentially the increase in inductance at pull in causes a drop in AC current. That makes sense.

Comment: @RoyC Sure, there will be a change in inductance when the core moves but I'm genuinely referring to AC solenoids because they do exhibit inrush currents and can saturate causing bigger currents (for a few cycles of AC).

Comment: Very pretty diagrams would you mind attributing them so we can decide on their applicability. Current through an inductor is 1/L integral V dt plus initial current, initial current is zero. Can you please tell us where this inrush current is coming from, nothing in this equation explains that. Saturation is a function of field strength which is proportional to current, if the current is not increasing unreasonably you will not get saturation.

Comment: @RoyC the table was taken from here: http://www.olino.org/us/articles/2013/10/22/inrush-current-for-led-light-bulbs and the waveform one was a modified one taken from here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135601/transformer-inrush-protection. Unfortunately I can't remember where the 2nd one came from. However, that 2nd link is to an answer I gave on SE relating to inrush current in transformers.

Comment: @RoyC The integral of V starting from 0 deg and ending at 180 degrees produces the peak in current. That peak will cause more magnetic saturation of the ironwork in the AC solenoid/inductor/transformer and this lowers inductance leading to more peak current and the situation can get dramatically worse and blow fuses.

Comment: How is this different from the steady state condition, given that the initial current is 0?

Comment: @RoyC think about the steady state case as V rises through zero volts - the current begins at a negative value (-I). As integration proceeds during the first half cycle of the voltage the current rises from -I to +I. That's the steady state case. Now, if current is zero at t = 0 then current will peak at 2I at the end of the first half cycle of voltage. Do you think I deserved the down vote?

Comment: Thank you I have got it now the instantaneous current can drive the core into saturation, It might be worth putting your last comment into the answer.

Comment: "if the solenoid is connected to an AC source as it passes through zero volts then the current waveform in the solenoid can reach an excessive value that causes magnetic saturation of the solenoid core and make the problem of inrush even worse." why current waveform will reach excessive value if the solenoid is connected to an AC source as it passes through zero volts ? what is the reason ? @Andyaka

Comment: @Alex look at the waveform pictures.

Comment: i saw, when ac is supplied at 0 volts to the inductor will the current lag behind the voltage exactly by 90 degree from beginning to the end ? @Andyaka

Comment: No, it only does that with a sine wave and, importantly, a sine wave is only truly regarded as a pure sine wave when it has been cycling for a very long time. In the example above, the sine wave springs into action from nowhere and hence, the current cannot have been flowing in a natural way hence, the current does what it can and follows the inductor formula. There is no magic. It follows the formula v = L di/dt. Do the math, use a sim, or use excel to see that formula in action.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jack Creasey said the solenoid is basically an inductor so it does not have an inrush current. Solenoids are specified with the pull in current, enough current to pull in the solenoid; hold current, enough current to hold the solenoid pulled in and the DC resistance which allows you to calculate the maximum current for any applied voltage.

The amount of current a solenoid takes as it pulls in is a little more complex than a simple inductor. The inductance varies as the core is pulled into the solenoid giving a current profile like this.

[image]

Diagram credit:- http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/ssiy001/ssiy001.pdf

Comment: An inductor can certainly have an inrush current when fed from an AC supply. When fed from a DC supply no, there is no inrush current. I think you need to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a relay, rather than a solenoid, 'make current' refers to the switching capacity of the contacts, not the coil current.

Comment: @Armadillo 2001 are we talking about a solenoid or a relay?