# Is AC relay "inrush" current caused by more than the mutual inductance effect?

Tags: current, ac, relay

My interest is in the "inrush" current of an AC relay. I took apart a 24VAC one. It's energized current was about 40mA but when I removed the plate that is pulled by the electromagnet, the current doubled (roughly). This leads me to believe that part of the inrush is at least due to fact that the plate has not been pulled into the closed position.

I'm curious as to why less current flows through the coil after the plate is pulled against the electromagnet.

Comment: Good question Doug.

Answer (score 11):

The "plate" is the relay armature.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [D&T Online](http://wiki.dtonline.org/index.php/Relays).*

When the armature is pulled in by the coil it closes the magnetic circuit. This results in an increase in coil inducatance and since the impedance (resistance to current flow) is given by \$ Z = 2\pi fL \$ it should be clear that for a given frequency the impedance will increase with the inductance. Your hunch is correct: the current will be high initially and reduce when the relay picks up.

This has the advantage that AC relays can be made to pull in strongly and automatically reduce their current when pulled-in. Be aware though that if the relay binds and remains energised while not pulling in that the coil may overheat and burn out. This can be a particular problem on larger contactors.

> Is AC relay “inrush” current caused by more than the mutual inductance effect?

There's no "mutual" in a relay. Mutual inductance would require one coil affecting another - and there is no other in this case.

---

> When the armature pulls in, it connects the two sides of the core - does this make the core in effect longer? That would explain the higher L!

No, it eliminates the air gap. Think of the air gap as a large magnetic circuit resistance due to air's poor permeability relative to the iron core. It's making a poor inductor. Close the air gap and now you have a good low reluctance magnetic circuit so the inductance increases.

Comment: Armature, right, I should have looked it up! Yes, a higher XL makes some sense to me. The core has a trench through the center with a copper ring around one side to create the pole effect.

Comment: Oops hit send by accident. At any rate, when the armature pulls in, it connects the two sides of the core - does this make the core in effect longer? That would explain the higher L!

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 6):

> *My interest is in the "inrush" current of an AC relay.*

@Transistor has clearly dealt with the situation of inductance increasing when the magnetics don't have a gap anymore - just regard the closing of the gap as producing a lot more magnetic permeability and, given that inductance of a coil is proportional to permeability, the AC current reduces when the gap is minimized.

Another problem is that inrush current also occurs when you activate the relay coil when the applied AC voltage is passing through 0 volts. This will cause the current in the first few dozen cycles to approximately double. If you activated the relay coil at the peak of the AC voltage then you would get no peaking of the current: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349176/what-is-the-difference-beteeen-a-solenoids-make-current-and-inrush-current/349203#349203).

Comment: I think I'm getting the picture. L = N^2 X u0n X a / l

Comment: Great answers Andy and Transistor.  That has always bugged me - how current is higher when mag circuit air-core then much lower when changed to low reluctance core.  Is there an intuitive “why” we can state?  Not just equations say so, but physical why.

Comment: @relayman357 not sure what it is you want stating in more detail. Can you be clearer cause I'd hate to drone on about this or that when you meant something else.

Comment: Thanks Andy, you are very clear.  It just bothers me that the current is higher for air core. Then, when we put a nice magnetic material for the flux to flow through the current goes down. Something about that is counterintuitive to me.

Comment: @relayman357 OK I see what you say. With a closed magnetic path the magnetic reluctance is much lower therefore, for a given current, more flux is produced ([LINK1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance#:~:text=Magnetic%20reluctance%2C%20or%20magnetic%20resistance,and%20composition%20of%20an%20object.)). If there is more flux per amp then there is more inductance ([LINK2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Source_of_inductance)).

Comment: I believe I’m thinking clearly now. For both cases (high reluctance and low-reluctance) The volts per turn of the coil is the same (e.g. same 24V applied).  Faraday’s [induction law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) in differential form makes it clear that (with fixed magnitude AC voltage applied) the rate of change of total flux (flux linkage) must be the same as well for both cases.  And as Andy elucidates above, with lower reluctance magnetic path of the later case, this requires less current.

Comment: I was fooling around with my ac relay today which, by the way, has been sacrificed in my search. I pulled off the copper ring from the end of the core which I think eliminates the shaded part of the coils effect. When I applied the same AC voltage as before, the armature started vibrating which was expected, of coarse. When I physically pulled the armature away from the coil, the current went up to about 80mA but when I pushed it against the coil, the current only went down to about 60mA. Before I pulled the copper ring, the current would go down to 40mA. Curious.

Comment: The fact that the current still went down without the copper ring substantiates that the permeability of the coil is going up. But mA didn't go down as far as with the ring so is there another effect going on or is it just because I changed the core when I removed the copper? Copper's relative u is pretty close to air so I didn't think that removing it would make much difference. And the currents the same when the armature is unclosed. Why doesn't it go down as far?. I originally suggested that mutual inductance might play a part because I thought there was some from shaded to unshaded core.

Comment: @DougWeiss I think that deserves a new question because then it would also attract anyone wishing to throw in their lot on shaded pole motors. But, to do it justice, pictures or diagrams might help as well as a link to the relay data sheet.

Comment: I'm new to this venue - this was my first question and I'm really enjoying the responses! I think I'll take your advice and redo the whole thing with the documentation you suggested. I'll need to get another AC relay because I don't think I can put the old one back together. It's interesting that you mentioned shaded pole motors because that's what I'm really interested in. I decided to start with AC relays as a launch point. If I can understand them, I think it will help with my understanding that type of motor.

Comment: @DougWeiss please leave this question intact and ask a new one. Also feel free to formally accept the most appropriate answer to this question.